# How can I connect to a MySQL web server with Java?

Tags: java, mysql

Alright, so here's a little bit of background:

I am currently trying to develop a referral application. There is a link on our website where a user can refer their friends to our game server (Minecraft). It will input the referrer's information into a database (hosted on my website) and send a link to the "friend". The friend clicks on the link and enters their information (which also gets stored in the database). All of this is working great! (Yay!) So, now for the Java Plugin!

**What is supposed to happen...**

I have an Event Listener that will fire whenever a user logs into the game. Essentially, it would check the data base for the user's info, and if the user meets the criteria, then it will award them with their extra referral goodies.

**What I am trying to do right now...**

Right now, I am essentially trying to just get it to connect and display the id of the row, and the ref_id (Referral ID) when the plugin is enabled. But, I'm getting the following error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

So, without further ado, here is my singular Java document. Of course, that is not the real username and login information to my database. ;) But I'm hoping someone here can tell me what's wrong, because I'm so lost, right now.

```
package com.arithia.plugins;

import java.sql.*;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerLoginEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;


public class ArithiaReferrals extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {
    // JDBC driver name and database URL
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://66.147.244.122:3306/graphja6_referrals";

    // Database credentials
    static final String USER = "fake_username";
    static final String PASS = "fake_password";

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;

        try {
            // STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // STEP 3: Open a connection
            getLogger().info("Connecting to database...");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

            // STEP 4: Execute a query
            getLogger().info("Creating statement...");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String sql;
            sql = "SELECT id, ref_id FROM referred_users";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            // STEP 5: Extract data from result set
            while(rs.next()) {
                // Retrieve by column name
                int id = rs.getInt("id");
                int ref_id = rs.getInt("ref_id");

                // Display values
                getLogger().info("ID: " + id);
                getLogger().info("Referral ID: " + ref_id);
            }

            // STEP 6: Clean-up environment
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        }catch(SQLException se) {
            // Handle errors for JDBC
            se.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            // finally block used to close resources
            try{
                if(stmt!=null)
                    stmt.close();
            }catch(SQLException se2){
            } // nothing we can do
            try {
                if(conn!=null)
                    conn.close();
            }catch(SQLException se){
                se.printStackTrace();
            } // End Finally try
        } // end try
        getLogger().info("Goodbye!");
        getLogger().info("The [Arithia Referrals] plugin was enabled!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        getLogger().info("The [Arithia Referrals] plugin was disabled!");
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerLogin(PlayerLoginEvent e) {
        // "Check database for player..."
    }
}
```

**Other Information...**

*Database Name:* graphja6_referrals

*Database Table:* referred_users

*Note:* I am not entirely sure that the `DB_URL` is correct... `66.147.244.122` is the correct IP, but I'm not entirely sure about the port or anything else, so if someone could verify that's correct, I'd be appreciative.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Please remove [tag:php] tag

Comment: I tried to edit it but it was already gone. My apologies. I'm using PHP to create the database and such, which is why I included it. I think it's fixed now. Sorry about that.

Comment: is that possible that it is a firewall-related issue (on client and/or the server) ? is that port open on your server?

Comment: are you sure the remote server allows remote connection?

Comment: @RafaelOsipov I'm not sure. How can I check to see if the port is open on the server?

Comment: @M.Sharma Checking now.

Comment: @Lindsay you can check it via telnet: https://kb.acronis.com/content/7503

Comment: @Lindsay [this online tool](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) shows that default MySQL port `3306` is closed on the server with ip `66.147.244.122`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I'm just an idiot.

For anyone else getting this error, you need to whitelist the IP of the remote connection for this to work. It is a firewall thing, and depending on who you host with, there's probably a "Remote MySQL" option in the cPanel. Add the IP to the remote client that is trying to access the database, so it will be whitelisted.

Thank you to everyone who tried to help. <3

Comment: thats what is asked you for